# rake aborted Permission denied - /home/u/eol/db/structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I run the command:

```
rake eol:db:recreate RAILS_ENV=development
```

And this happens:

> rake aborted!
>   Permission denied - /home/u/eol/db/structure.sql

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions for your `db` directory, it seems your user does not have write permission for it.

Make sure the entire app directory and its subfolders belong to your user:

```
chown -R `whoami` /home/u/eol
```

And add the write permission to all folders:

```
chmod -R u+w /home/u/eol
```

Comment: @ZhangQingLong so did this solve your issue? If yes, please accept the answer. If no, please answer your own question to help future visitors and then accept that. Thanks!